# Entity Framework 4.1 code first SQL Server Compact 4 in Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms, entity, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use SLQ server compact edition 4 together with entityframework 4.1 with code-first approach in a Windows form application.
In asp.NET MVC there are plenty of tutorials, but I can't find any help for windows form applications.

I did the following steps:

- Created a windows form application
- Created a new project class library called "library_database"
- Created some classes and a DbContext
- Created a app.config file in the project and a connection string to a database file with name equal to my DbContext class name

Now when I try to access my DbContext to add a new object, the application hangs and doesn't stop without returning any exception.

How is this possible?
Can you suggest me an approach, tutorial or anything to start?
Consider that I can use EF code-first with asp.NET MVC but I never tried with windows applications

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this tutorial for WPF - also make sure the catch thrown exceptions when debugging!  http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Comment: OP actually asked for WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: I know... but the Data Access and projects structure will be the same/similar

Comment: It should not be different in WPF and even ASP.NET

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, thanks for your help. In your code you use a objectContext, I would prefer the approach of using a dbContext with CodeFirst. To understand us better, something as simple as http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs. This tutorial doesn't work for me with windows applications!

Comment: Sounds like you have done the proper steps, must look at a code repro in order to help further

Comment: I actually made it work right now, but I still have problems with the connectionstring. Should it be placed in app.config file of the project right? I cannot see that the database file is created, even if a specify a path like "C:\myDB.sdf"